# Continuous Simulation - Performance tuning - GPU/CPU

Tags: c#, gpu, cpu, simulation

I constructed a continuous simulation model (state based) for the mining industry.  Equipment is tracked for engineering and production purposes, where equipment states are updated when events happen, such as breakdowns, production events etc.  Many statistical distributions are used.  For illustration purposes, see below code to get an idea of how the simulation works.

I'm trying to optimize performance.  Basically thousands of 'cases' need to be run.  I can run x amount of cases in parallel, based on the amount of physical threads available to me.  Thus the CPU works at 100%.

A 1000 cases can take more than a day to run.

From the structure of the application, is there an opportunity to introduce GPU calculations?  I have never programmed with a GPU and would like to know if there is opportunity for me to include the GPU in my calculations somehow.  Any other advice will also be appreciated.

```
public static void RunAll()
{
   //This list contains thousands cases
   List<SimCase> simCases = ImportCases()

   //List which contains simulation results
   ConcurrentBag<Results> resultsList = new ConcurrentBag<Results>();

   //Runs cases in parallel (consumes all threads)
   Parallel.ForEach(simCases, simCase =>
   {
      var results = RunSimulation(simCase);
      resultsList.Add(results);
   });

  //Interpret results and build report
}

public static Results RunSimulation(SimCase simCase)
{
   Results results = new Results();

   DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(2018,1,1);
   DateTime finalDate= new DateTime(2018,12,31);

   while (currentDate < finalDate)
   {
      //Many if statements

      //Many object updates

      //Many functions calls to libraries for statistical calcs

      //Updates simulation time
      currentDate = currentDate.addSeconds(1);
   }

   return(results);
}
```

Comment: I currently have an i7-5600U 2.6GHZ with 2 physical cores.  I'll most likely get an AMD Ryzen 16/32 core to greatly speed up things.  However I would like to investigate if a GPU can be used somehow

Comment: While your problem is embarrassingly parallel, It's impossible to answer without knowing exactly what kind of calculations are done.

Comment: It depends whether all cores will run exactlyx the same code all the time. If yes - possible. If no - you can ggo much higher on a proper server or server farm. That problem sounds like it can use some queueing/worker mechanism.

Comment: Have you profiled the code? I'd recommend ANTS performance profiler. There's a 14 day free trial on their website: https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/index

Comment: Unfortunately the code is thousands of lines, so I cannot share it here.  I also don't think you would want to spend hours delving into that.  The structure however is the same as given above.  The many lines of code is List<> interactions, if statements, calls to Math.Net for distributions, Object updates etc.

Imagine a list of 1000 equipment where things happen to them every second.  Positions are updated.  States are changed.  Events happen to them etc

Comment: I have not profiled the code.  I'll do that and see if there is some flaw somewhere

Comment: These kinds of simulations normally tend to be heavily computational extensive.  A consultant using Simio (commercial sim application) built a similar simulation and theirs took 10 times longer than mine.  So I'm confident my code is OK, but want to speed it up as much as I can.

Comment: @TomTom - the code is exactly the same for each iteration.  The parameters however are different.  It's basically one complicated Monte Carlo simulation with about 500+ distributions being called to determine performance of the whole value chain

Comment: The trick is that monte carlo IS the same code - you run it against a data set, but every branch has the same data and does the same formulas. This means you can run parallel SIMD style instructiosn. You can not when you have diferent branches depending on parameter.

Comment: @TomTom I'll do some research on SIMD.  And as you said, the code is the same.    Predefined distributions produce the different parameters for each Case.  Unfortunately I'm not a software engineer.  I'm a self taught programmer with a Chem Eng degree, so have a lot to learn

Comment: You might find statistical design of experiments and response surface metamodeling useful.  See "[Work Smarter, Not Harder: A Tutorial on Designing and Conducting Simulation Experiments](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc15papers/187.pdf)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a GPU won't help much in my case, as my program is heavily reliant on third party math libraries, if statements and object iterations/updates.  What did give me 50% performance improvement was the following:

- Change all .Count() to .Count on Lists
- Change all .Count() to .Length on Arrays
- Change .Count() == 0 expression to .Any() on IEnumerable collections

I'll invest in a 32 thread CPU to greatly speed up things.